# Image still attached to post even after removing it as featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, media, wp-list-table

I'm sorry if this is too noob of a question, but when I upload an image and set it as the featured image then later remove it (as featured image), the media list still shows it's "Attached to" the post I removed it as featured image from. Any clue?

More importantly, how do I then make it so that when I remove the featured image, it will be "Unattached"? Any hook I can attach to or the like?

Thanks so much.

Comment: you can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/file-gallery/ to detach media files

Answer (score 2):

Any image uploaded to a post in the post editor is "attached to" that post. Actually, you can only set an attached image as Featured Image (aka [Post Thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) -- not to be confused with "Thumbnails"), and it's NOT vice-versa.

If you do not want an image to be attached to a post, you can upload the image directly to the Media Library (via **WordPress Dashboard** > **Media** > **Add New**) and then use the image in your post (from the **From URL** tab in the media uploader in the post editor).

Comment: thanks, but i have no issue with that. i can even set an unattached image as Featured Image/Post Thumbnail. what i need is after removing the Featured Image using the "Remove featured image" link in the Featured Image metabox when editing this post type, i don't want the just-removed image to still show up as "Attached" on the media list.

Comment: @AnaBan Looks like this is what you need? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/file-un-attach/

Comment: @AnaBan And there's another one as well: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/file-gallery/